# Cursor always returns NULL for fetching path from file explorer for local video

Tags: android

*Always getting null in cursor object  while fetching path for video from local storage*

```
public String getPath(Uri uri){
    Log.i(TAG,"inside getpath");
    String[] filePathColumn={MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    Log.i(TAG,"bloody cursor = "+cursor);if (cursor != null) {
        // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
        // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.i(TAG,"exit  if get path");
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else{
        Log.i(TAG,"exit else get path");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Error Log as Below :

```
03-11 15:10:04.415 1758-1758/com.example.vivekgandhi.playvideoapp I/MyMessage: bloody cursor = null 
03-11 15:10:04.415 1758-1758/com.example.vivekgandhi.playvideoapp I/MyMessage: exit else get path
```

Comment: aim of this app is to let user browse video from local storage and play that video in this app.
source -> https://github.com/gandhivivek96/PlayVideoApp
or https://github.com/gandhivivek96/VideoApp
please help me:)

Comment: you can get path from uri.getPath();

Comment: you already have `Uri selectedImage=data.getData();` so use it in `vidView.setVideoURI()` method

Comment: thanks it helped me @pskink can you also me explain me the flow ? Intent gallery = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, SELECT_IMAGE);
what does it means?

Comment: `startActivityForResult` ? you dont know what it is used for?

Comment: to get result from another activity

Comment: so what part is not clear?